# How to prevent Excel files from getting quarantined?

Tags: macos, ms-office, filesystem

I'm using Excel for Mac, version 16.16.14 (190909). I'm running Catalina 10.15 Beta (19A558d).

All files I edit with Excel are recently quarantined (checking with `ls -la@`):

`com.apple.quarantine     30B`

It does not matter if the files have Macros in them or not, this happens to every single Excel file I edit. It seems like a bug in Catalina Gatekeeper.

Is there any way can I prevent this or how I can find out more about it?

Comment: I think you're going to need to add more info here. Is this happening after you edit the files, or were they already tagged with the extended attribute `com.apple.quarantine` ? And, are these macro-enabled files or...? I can't see why this would happen to plain ordinary .xls or .xlsx files, so I feel like we're missing some context here?

Comment: @Monomeeth Thanks for your comment. I added more information to the original post. This happens after I edit the files, right now I remove the attributes with `xattr -rc .`, but they are added again and again. It does not matter if macro-enabled or not. Sometimes the attribute has a size of `-1B`, and cannot be removed. After a while the size changes to `30B` and it can be removed.

Comment: Okay, well, now that we know you're running the Catalina beta, I suggest you report this to Apple because, as your edit says, *It seems like a bug in Catalina Gatekeeper*.

Comment: I already reported it, I was just curious if there is a way to see why this actually happens - how to see if Gatekeeper has certain applications flagged in an internal database (there is no quarantine flag on Excel, I checked).

Comment: Are you curious about how this works generally, or curious about this specific situation?

Comment: Both actually. I want to know how Gatekeeper works, how it decides to flag files and where the information about this is stored. I already read something about the format of the xattr. Ideally there is a way to change/configure more about Gatekeeper in general (even if it would mean to tinker around in SQlite databases).